# Unable to confirm a JUnit passing result

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

I created an automated test using JUnit and selenium on ebay that:

- navigates to page, logs in, searches for items, adds them to chart, navigates to cart page and counts the items from cart.

  Everything works fine but I have no clue how should a create a junit test that confirms that the test case is passing. Expected number of items from cart equals to `located_elements.size()`, because everything depends on the cart page when the test case comes to end.

```java
    import java.util.List;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    public class Ebay_06_Login_BuyItNow_Add_3_ItemsToBasket_Checkout {
        public static void main(String[] args){
    //NAVIGATE TO PAGE
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\work\\Selenium\\Chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.ebay.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            
    //LOG IN
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gh-ug\"]/a")).click();                                                                       // click sign in button
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Email or username'])")).sendKeys("name@yahoo.com");       //find user field and enter user
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='password'][@placeholder='Password'][@class='fld'])")).sendKeys("testautomation123!");  //find password field and enter password
            driver.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();                                                                                         //click "sign in" button
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='m_t10'])")).click();                                                                    //click "maybe later" button
            
    //SEARCH FOR ITEM
            driver.findElement(By.id("gh-ac")).sendKeys("BMW E30 M3 1/43 scale");                                                               //find search field
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit'][@class='btn btn-prim gh-spr']")).click();                                      //click "search" button
            
            
    //ADD 1st ITEM FROM "BUY IT NOW" RESULTS LIST TO BASKET
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='small cbx btn btn-s btn-ter tab tgl_button last_b'][@title='Buy It Now']")).click();       //"buy it now" items already selected from previous search
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='sresult lvresult clearfix li'][@r='1']//div[@class='lvpic pic img left']")).click();      //select 1st item from results list
            driver.findElement(By.id("isCartBtn_btn")).click();                                                                                 //add to cart
            driver.findElement(By.id("contShoppingBtn")).click();                                                                               //continue shopping button
    
            System.out.println("1st item from results list successfully ADDED TO BASKET");
            
    //SEARCH FOR 2nd ITEM
            driver.findElement(By.id("gh-ac")).clear();                                                                                         //clear the field in order to perform new search
            driver.findElement(By.id("gh-ac")).sendKeys("BMW E46 M3 1/43 scale");                                                               //find search field
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit'][@class='btn btn-prim gh-spr']")).click();                                      //click "search" button
    
            
    //ADD 2nd ITEM FROM "BUY IT NOW" RESULTS LIST TO BASKET
                                                                                                                                                //"buy it now" already selected from previous search    
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='sresult lvresult clearfix li'][@r='1']//div[@class='lvpic pic img left']")).click();      //select 1st item from results list
            driver.findElement(By.id("isCartBtn_btn")).click();                                                                                 //add to cart
                                                                    
            System.out.println("2nd item from results list successfully ADDED TO BASKET");
    
    
    
                List<WebElement> located_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'sellerBucket')]"));                      //check total number of items added to cart by counting them
                System.out.println("Total number of items in cart are: " +located_elements.size());
            
    //      driver.quit();
    
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assert the locatedelements.size() with expected:

```
Assert.assertEquals(located_elements.size(), xxx); 
//Replace xxx with the number of elements you expect
```

Comment: Accepted answer with -1 votes. Rarely noticed this. +1 for the accepted answer. I am assuming that if the answer is accepted, it has helped the person asking the question in some way.